# Database design to filter report by address location

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, erd

Consider the case where I'm modeling a database for managing parking lots.

- Entities: `Company`, `ParkingLot`, `Location`, `Vehicle` and
  `Reports`.
- A `Company` has multiple `ParkingLots` and a ParkingLot can have multiple `Vehicles` at a time.
- A `ParkingLot` is located in a district, which belong to a county. A county can have one or more districts, for this I decided to use a recursive relationship in a table called `Location`.
- `Reports` are made for `ParkingLots` to calculate incomes, Im assuming it is on a monthly basis because the text doesn't specify.
- `Reports` should be able to be filtered by county, i.e Select all incomes of this month from the Lots in county no.2.

Please excuse my ugly diagram, but this is the solution I came with.

[image]

I ran some rudimentary tests and it seems to be acceptable as a solution, but I worry if my model can support the last point I made. Which is getting al the report of a county's parking lots. A parking lot is assigned not to a county but to a district (which is assigned to its respective county).

Is this a viable solution? Is there some grave oversight I've made?

EDIT:

Is it posible to get all the Lots where the FK id_location matches with a FK located_at = PK id_location (county)?

EDIT2:

While the recursive table may be a bit more complex doesn't the different parts of the address on different table takes the same amount of steps to generate a report?

In the recursive: Get all the selected county's districts, then for each parking lot on those counties get the reports that are stored.

County and District Table: I still have to get a list of all the county's districts to get the report list. The query for this model would be less confusing though.

Also added `report_date` to the Report table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments:

- Does `REPORT` need to be a table? Should you be recording how much money each car paid in the vehicle table?  If so, you can create your report via a query and you don't need a `REPORT` table.
- Using a recursive relationship on `LOCATION` makes it more difficult to query than if you had explicit tables.  Do you really need this complexity?
- If you do need the `REPORT` table, then you better put a month in there or you can only store data for one month.

Comment: Because this case's scope is purely DB oriented, there is no other way I found to represent the concept of reports, likewise the text didn't specify if it needed to be a table or not, I'll of course take in consideration your point. For the recursive relationship I decided on it based on the following article; http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=recursive.php  Also I added a report date (month) to the table, because you're quite right.